# Is there a Hash nil check for fetch?

Tags: ruby, hash, fetch, null

I'm using the facebook graph-api and I'm fetching the checkin keys. Most places have this checkin key, but every once in a while I find a place with no checkins that does not have this key. Is there a way to check for nil and prevent the following code from blowing up my very large rake?

```
graph.get_object(5811874893).fetch("checkins")
KeyError: key not found: "checkins"


x =  graph.get_object(x.place_id)["checkins"]
```

Based on feedback below I have the following error, with the same theme: nil checking. How would you handle this?

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried seeing if `has_key?` is available, or using `graph.get_object(5811874893)["checkins"]` rather than `graph.get_object(5811874893).fetch("checkins")`?

To return 0 if there isn't checkins, do

```
graph.get_object(5811874893).fetch("checkins") { 0 }
```

The block after `fetch` specifies what to do if `"checkins"` doesn't exist.

Comment: This works but it results in 2 api calls when I only need one. Is there a better way?

Comment: @JZ: Check the new version of my answer.

Comment: You don't actually need a block here, you could just pass this as a second argument `foo.fetch("checkins", 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```
graph.get_object(5811874893)["checkins"]
```

If you access a hash using `[]`, no error will be raised, and you'll get a nil value (as long as the hash doesn't set it to something else).

Comment: This works, but returns nil. Is there a way to check for nil and if so return zero?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
graph.get_object(5811874893).fetch("checkins", 0)
```

*fetch* accepts a second optional param which represents the default value.